# Wifi Network is found, but cannot connect

Tags: 14.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have an HP Pavilion 15 e020us, and ubuntu 14.04 is partitioned on it. My home network is a connection in the network settings, and the password for the network is saved there. However, when I select my network to connect, it will load for awhile and then display the message that I have been disconnected from a wireless network. I have connected to my computer via ethernet, and checked for updates, but it did not find any.

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:197d]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I have posted what you asked for.

Comment: Is that sufficient for you to determine the issue?

Comment: It is sufficient to determine the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work :(